# Should we have a generic tag for DSLs or just specialized ones?

Tags: discussion, tags

Are there any benefits of a general tag for [Domain Specific Languages (DSL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) in the opposite of having specific tags based on technologies like tags for  [MPS](https://www.jetbrains.com/mps/), [Langium](https://langium.org/), and [XText](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/)?

Answer (score 5):

Having general tags isn't a good idea most of the time. I don't know about this topic so I'm not one to say but what should be looked at is if you can answer most questions that would have the tag. Like the `python` tag on Stack Overflow then they have tags for specific versions like `python-3.x`.

So if it's something that you could answer most questions yes you should have general and specific tags. If not only specific tags.

Comment: [tag:python] and [tag:python-3.x] on Stack Overflow is a bad example because the latter tag is commonly used for questions that are not specific to Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

What about questions for DSLs in general, like "What makes a language a DSL?", "How can I write a DSL?" "What are the advantages and disadvantages of writing a DSL?"

The tag `dsl-meta` would clarify that this isn't for questions on specific DSLs.

Answer (score 2):

## No

Unless there's some reason to think questions about DSLs for different domains will have anything to do with each other.